# relative smoth direction from a point to a polygon (not shortest). In Python or C

Tags: python, c, geometry, linear-algebra, raycasting

I'm trying to have the smooth direction from a point to a polygon mesh.
It's not the shortest path direction but one that is interpolated from the mesh normals.

The way I'm going about it is to "extrude" the points of polygons along their normals with linePlane intersection between each prim point and normal and a plande defined by P and the plane normal.

I guess the first issue is assess to which polygon the point will belong to. I using a clumbsy way but sort of works. What's bothering me the most is actually after "extruding" the points and making the polygon co-planar with the point, I need to find on the orginal polygon the same relative position it has in the extruded one.

I can raycast, so I was wondering if I could just infer somehow the direction back to the orginal poly and get the corresponding position with its hit.

Is is this a common problem with a name, any references I should check?

Rationale:

[image]

Comment: the *"Python or C"* part of this question is somewhat questionable in a Stack Overflow question, when you're looking for an algorithm, and present no code

Comment: You'll want to head over to math.stackexchange.com to ask this question. However, you should try to explain *the problem you are trying to solve*. Right now, you are asking for help with your chosen solution without reference to the actual problem, which means all who read your question just go *"Huh?"*, then ask you to clarify exactly what you are doing (*"smooth direction"* is as clear a term as *"yellow scent"* is), or *"What are you trying to achieve by doing that?"*. Asking a good question -- something that can be answered positively -- takes quite a bit of effort!